# Passing a variable to systemd service start doesn't work

Tags: systemd

Ubuntu 18.04

foundry-error.service

```
[Unit]
Description= /home/man/errorpage/error_pages.js - User errorpage.
Documentation=https://blah.com
After=network.target

[Service]
Environment=NODE_PORT=%i

Type=simple
User=man
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /home/man/errorpage/error_pages.js
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I try to pass the port to the start up.

```
systemctl start foundry-error@8000
systemctl start foundry-error@8000.service
systemctl start foundry-error.service@8000
```

All of these iterations come back with "Unit ... not found."  So I am not sure how to pass the port # in as I need to pass in 3 different ports.  I have done this from root, and from sudo man.  All to the same issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass flags when starting a systemd service?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077778/how-do-i-pass-flags-when-starting-a-systemd-service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service file should be named `foundry-error@.service`. Yours is missing the at sign.
Also, make sure it is in the correct directory (usually `/etc/systemd/system/`).

The first two ways of invoking the service are correct. The last one is invalid.